# Scour Nodes in IE8

Tags: javascript

I use a Javascript function to scour a html page and search and replace a string.
But this function don't work in IE7 and IE8. The problem come from the using of `childNodes`.
Have you a source or a script (compatible with IE 7/8)for search and replace a string in all the element of the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pure javascript function [Replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: I use this function and it work. But for find the element to replace i must scour all element of the DOM : and it is the problem.  A function like this http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/find-and-replace-text-with-javascript/ dont work in IE7/8, i search a compatible method with IE7/8. Thanks